# Why does this Summation code give no output?

Tags: java, sum

The code is shown here below:
it is supposed to be a simple summation program for:
X = sum of 5 to power i,from i= 1-50, in increments of 1. 
Answer is supposed to be X = 1.110223E35 but gives no output.

thanks

```
public class JavaApplication7 {
int start, end, inc;
void Sum_calc(){
int i;
float X, Total;
    Total =0f;
   for(i=start; i<=end; i=i+inc)               
    Total = Total + (float) Math.pow(5f,i);
System.out.println("X +" +  Total); 
}

public static void main(String arguments[]){
Summation j = new Summation();//Create a new object
j.start = 1;
j.end = 50;
j.inc = 1;
j.Sum_calc();//Call calculation method

}    
}
```

Comment: I ran this code on compilejava.net and got X +1.1102231E35, I had to rename your class to summation, but it works as expected

Comment: Also, why not use a long if you're not using a decimal?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the line:

```
 Summation j = new Summation();//Create a new object
```

with:

```
JavaApplication7 j = new JavaApplication7();//Create a new object
```

`Summation` is another class that has a method name `Sum_calc` too but it is not printing anything.